# Screen Reader not reading the page when navigated with keyboard on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, accessibility

When the user navigates to a new page by clicking the Link component the screen reader reads the new page perfectly and in correct order. If the user selects the new page by pressing enter or space the browser still navigates to the correct page but the screen reader does not read the page content.

The code to new page navigation looks like this:

```
  <Card className={classes.root}>
     <Link to={`/event/${eventId}`} component={CardActionArea}>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
        />
        <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
              ...some info..
        </CardContent>
     </Link>
  </Card>
```

I tried to solve this by creating a keyDownEvent as follows but it was no use:

```
 const elementRef = React.createRef<HTMLAnchorElement>();

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
      elementRef.current.click();
    }
  }
```

and called it in the Link

```
  <Link to={`/event/${eventId}`} component={CardActionArea} onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}>
```

Anyone have an idea as to where I am going wrong or what I should give a try?

Comment: are you correctly updating the URL if they use the keyboard? Check your router is correctly updating the page URL when you press Enter or Space first. If not manage focus to the `<h1>` on the page after it loads. I can put an answer down if the first option doesn't work on how to do that (general guidance, I am not good with React!).

Comment: Yeah it does navigate to the exact same URL. Would be greatfull if you could let me know how to select h1 because I searched a bit and it seemed that only input elements could be focused on. I think I can figure out the react bit if I know what I am suppose to do

Comment: No problem, I have put something together for you to follow. Let me know if you need any further clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not able to tell you how to do this in React but it is a straightforward process so I am sure you won't struggle. The key part to fix your issue is the "after navigation" heading, however try to implement everything if you can as it will vastly improve screen reader user experience.

### SPA pattern best practices for navigation

The method recommended for handling navigation in SPAs is actually quite straight forward with two steps.

1. tell a user that navigation is about to occur (before navigation)
2. let a user know that loading is complete (after navigation).

#### before navigation (link click)

You need to signal to a user that a page is loading if you are using a SPA pattern (and therefore interrupting normal navigation). e.g. I click your link, you need to let me know that an action is being performed (loading.....) as you intercept the normal browser behaviour with `e.preventDefault()` or equivalent.

The simplest way is to use [`aria-live=assertive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) on a region that explains the page is loading. You can Google how to implement that correctly but essentially you would update the content of a hidden div (`<div aria-live="assertive" class="visually-hidden">loading</div>`) with some loading message the second a link is clicked.

This should be done **before any AJAX calls** are made.

#### after navigation (new content loaded)

When the new page loads you need to manage focus.

The best way to do this is to add a level 1 heading (`<h1>`) to each page that has `tabindex="-1"`. By using `tabindex="-1"` it means that the heading won't be focusable by anything other than your JavaScript so won't interfere with the normal document flow.

Once the page loads and the content has been populated fully the **last action** you perform in your JavaScript navigation function is to place the focus onto this heading.

This has two benefits:

1. it lets the user know where they are now
2. it also lets them know when the page load is complete (as AJAX navigation doesn't announce when the page is loaded in most screen readers).

At this point you may also want to clear the `<div aria-live="assertive">` contents so that it is ready for further navigation.

Comment: could you provide some code for the "after navigation".  I cannot get the screenreader to announce the new page with the following:-

constructor     this.focusMe = React.createRef()
componentDidMount  this.focusMe.current.focus()
<Typography tabIndex={-1} variant={"h1"}  ref={this.focusMe}>abc</Typography>