# Screen reader accessibility in HTML page for headings

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a page with 2 headings at the top that set the intention of the page (h1 for the main heading, followed by h2 for the sub-heading). For screen reader accessibility, I wish to make sure that every time the page loads, both the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags are read out by the screen reader. The reading sequence should be `<h1>` followed by `<h2>` and the HTML looks like:

```
    <h1 id='myHeading'>ABCD</h1> 
    <h2>DEF</h2>
```

My application uses JS, HTML and CSS. Programmatically how do I make the headings announced by the screen reader, when this page loads? In other words, what HTML/aria attributes should I add on the header tag so the screenreader reads it out as soon as the page is done loading?

Comment: Could you give an example of your HTML?

Comment: Sure, added it in the question above

Comment: Why did you choose to not put a space between the words screenreader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expected behaviour is key to accessibility, trying to force something to be the way **you want it** vs how it *should* behave very rarely improves accessibility.

If both the items are together (without any text between) as you indicate and are both essential for identifying the page purpose and location I would suggest you make the whole thing a `<h1>` and use styling to make a visual distinction.

```css
h1{
   font-size: 46px;
}
h1>span{
   font-size: 24px;
   line-height: 36px;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='myHeading'>ABCD <br/>
    <span>DEF</span></h1>
```

However if that then breaks the logical heading structure of your page then you cannot do that.

Everything else I could suggest would make the page less robust and introduce unexpected behaviour.

The only thing I would say is if the `<h1>` is not descriptive enough then improve the `<h1>` itself, this will probably improve the page for everyone. Don't worry if you end up with some slight duplication in the following `<h2>` if that is a logical name for the section.

Comment: You are correct, I understand. However, my question was geared towards how to programmmaticlly make the headings read out to a screen reader? As in, which aria attributes can I use for this. Eg role="live/assertive" etc that would qualify in this scenario for the header HTML tags

Comment: Can you explain in detail exactly what you are trying to achieve and why? I did try to explain in my answer that trying to make a screen reader read both headings as one would result in hacks (less robust) and probably not work. Are you trying to fix a problem that doesn't actually exist by any chance and are you familiar with how screen reader users navigate a page? I think if I understand the scenario better I can offer better advice.

Comment: Also FYI its "headings" not "headers" as otherwise people may get confused and think your are talking about the `<header>` element, rather than a `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

Comment: Hello, so my question is : Say my HTML page has just an <h1>. How do I make sure that screen reader announces this <h1> as soon as page is done loading?

Comment: If the end user has auto read switched on on their screen reader then it will read page title and then the `<h1>` by default. Is this an AJAX application by any chance? If so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649777/2702894) shows how to handle navigating in a Single Page Application (SPA). Otherwise DO NOTHING is this is just a standard web page. Other than that I am still not following why you want to do this, screen reader users will automatically read the headings on a page in most circumstances using the keys 1-6.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much - that answers my query directly. thank you for your time.

Comment: no problem, I thought I wasn't quite understanding, glad I finally got what you meant! Glad it helped, good luck with the project!

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not clarifying that better!